# Are regex functions like "regexec" thread safe in libc version 2.2.5?

Tags: regex, linux, gcc, thread-safety, libc

I've read that regex functions in the libc should be threadsafe, but I've also read that in earlier version it was not the case.

I now have to work on an embedded system that has an old libc version 2.2.5 .

So I'm not really sure if functions like "regexec" are thread safe or if they should be protected by a mutex?

If anyone has any clue about this, I would be grateful. I'm also not very sure about what I should test against to verify the thread safety of these functions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are posix regcomp and regexec threadsafe? In specific, on GNU libc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404574/are-posix-regcomp-and-regexec-threadsafe-in-specific-on-gnu-libc)

Comment: my question would be: "was it thread safe 10 years ago with version 2.2.5" ? And how can I check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I searched the NEWS file in a recent libc version (2.13) for the regex keyword. There is nothing about thread safety, but the following note :

```
Version 2.3    
...

Isamu Hasegawa contributed a completely new and POSIX-conformant implementation
of regex.
```

But according to [this](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-devel/200508/msg00040.html), there have been some concurrency issue after 2.3 so things does not look so good for 2.2.5

According to this very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404574/are-posix-regcomp-and-regexec-threadsafe-in-specific-on-gnu-libc) POSIX conformance means regexec must be thread safe, but it does not mean there is no concurrency bug in earlier version of the libc.