# Are the POSIX regex functions (regcomp, regexec) thread-safe?

Tags: regex, thread-safety, posix

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are posix regcomp and regexec threadsafe? In specific, on GNU libc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404574/are-posix-regcomp-and-regexec-threadsafe-in-specific-on-gnu-libc)

[POSIX: regcomp, regerror, regexec, regfree - regular expression matching](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/regcomp.html)

If they are not thread-safe, are there any other options?

For various reasons I cannot use BOOST.

Comment: Voting to close - my question is better written but is a dupe.